# Extract parameters from Haskell types with `DataKinds`

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds, type-kinds

GHC's `DataKinds` extension allows for defining types that are parametrized by some data. Is there some possible way to use these these parameters on the RHS of a function definition? For example, in Agda I could extract the length of a vector directly from its type without computing on its constructors:

```
length : Vec A n -> Nat
length {n = n} _ = n
```

Is there a possible way to do this in Haskell?

The reason I am interested in this is because I think it would be helpful for a project I'm doing, which is a custom Haskell library for calling Java in a type-safe way (as safe as it is possible to achieve). I thought instead of having a single type representing all Java objects I could have a type parametrized by a Java class name as a string (e.g. `JObject "java.math.BigDecimal"`), so that instances of different classes in Java would also have different types in their representations in Haskell. And if what I am asking here is possible, then it would allow for automatically computing the JNI type-signature string from the given Haskell type of a method, so that I could write something like

```hs
method <- findMethod "toString" :: IO (JMethod (JObject "java.math.BigDecimal") (IO JString))
```

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, types are erased, they do not exist at run time. `DataKinds` lets you use data constructors in types, but they are still erased. In a function of type `forall n. Vec A n -> Nat`, it's not possible to return `n` because it will be erased.

For `n` to not be erased, you would have a type `Vec A n` which depends on a run-time value `n`, which is what dependent types are about.

Dependent types are not a native feature of Haskell (yet). However, it is possible to emulate them using [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons). The type of `length` would then be `forall n. SingI n => Vec A n -> Nat`, where the `SingI` constraint provides a run-time reflection of `n`.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, types don't exist at runtime. They are used only to classify **expressions in the source code**, not **values at runtime**.

You can certainly have `data JObject (className :: Symbol) = ...`, and use that to enforce that a function that only works on objects of some particular Java class is never given a `JObject` for a different class name. You can even make sure that code that combines two Java objects of the same class is never given `JObject`s of mismatched classes, even in a polymorphic context where you don't know what the actual class name is. But all of that is talking about your *code*. At runtime when an actual `JObject` exists in memory, it simply does not contain the `className`. There's nothing to extract.

It **is** however possible to make something that has the *effect* of giving you access to the `className` as if it were a value rather than a type. What you need is a function you can call, parameterised on the `className` `Symbol` that will produce a runtime `String` value. In Haskell, the standard way to make a function that has different behaviour for each possible value of a type parameter is to use a type class. You just need a class with a method that gives you a `String` value, and then an instance for every possible `Symbol` that implements the method by returning a corresponding `String`. Simple!

Fortunately GHC actually has a builtin class with magic instances for every `Symbol`, so nobody has to write all these instances by hand. It's called [`KnownSymbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:KnownSymbol). The method `symbolSing @s` actually gives you an `SSymbol s` rather than directly giving you the `String`, but you can get it out by calling [`fromSymbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:fromSSymbol).

Apart from magically having an infinite number of discrete instances, the `KnownSymbol` class is a perfectly ordinary class. This means that you can't automatically get a `KnownSymbol` instance if all you have is a type parameterised on an unknown `Symbol`; you will have to ensure that you use the right constraints on your functions to flow through the `KnownSymbol` instance from where the `Symbol` was actually chosen into the place where you want to know what it was.

The `SSymbol` type is an example of a technique known as "singletons" (not to be confused with the "singleton pattern" in OO languages). It just mean a parameterised type whose values are in one-to-one correspondence with choice of the type parameter. i.e. `SSymbol s` is a separate type for each choice of a `Symbol` `s`; each of those types has only a single value (hence "singletons"), so knowing which value we have reveals what its corresponding `Symbol` was, even though the `Symbol` technically doesn't exist at runtime. Using these singleton types as the link allows more options than just having a class that directly links a type and a value, even though that isn't necessarily required in simple cases. If you're interested, the [`singletons` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) is a framework for defining and working with singleton types more generally (as opposed to the very few ones provided by `base` because they need compiler support for the "magic instances").

Answer (score 1):

This is actually doable. Demo:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
  {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
    
  import GHC.Types
  import GHC.TypeLits
  import Data.Proxy

  data JavaObj :: Symbol -> * where
     JavaObj :: JavaObj a

  getJavaObjClassName :: KnownSymbol a => JavaObj a -> String
  getJavaObjClassName (_ :: JavaObj a) = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy a)

  mbd = JavaObj :: JavaObj "java.math.BigDecimal"

  main = do
    putStrLn (getJavaObjClassName mbd)
```

Explanations.

1. String literals get promoted to `GHC.Types.Symbol` in type contexts, so we need to use that as our data kind.
2. `KnownSymbol a =>` is exactly what doesn't let `a` to be erased at run time. It drags a dictionary that can be used to recover the string (via `Proxy`).

(This may not be the most idiomatic way of doing this, I am not an expert in wild and wonderful Haskell extensions).